# Mahalanobis Distance with Null Values

Tags: statistics, outliers, mahalanobis

My input dataframe is;

```
Default1     Default2     Default3   ... Default10
10           4            5
4            6            10
5            7            3
15           3            3
2            7            10
4            8            -
6            -            -
9            -            -
```

Let's think of columns as the number of loan payment days of customers. In the data, all customers have a Default value at least once, so all have the value Default1. However, the customer may not have any other credits, so they may not have a value in other Default columns.

I want to determine the mahalanobis distance and the outlier in this data. How do you think I should go about it?